# Defining fstream inside a 'if' conditional

Tags: c++, if-statement, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30388527/3358771) there was the following code:

```
if (std::ifstream input("input_file.txt"))
  ;
```

Which seems convenient, limiting the scope of the 'input' variable to where it's confirmed to be valid, however neither VS2015 nor g++ seems to compile it. Is it some compiler specific thing or does it require some extra flags?

In VS2015 the IDE highlights "std::ifstream" and the "input_file.txt" as well as the last parentheses. "std::ifstream" is flagged with "Error: a function type is not allowed here".

VS2015 C++ compiler gives following errors:

- C4430    missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
- C2059    syntax error: '('

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code you have is not legal.. yet.  Prior to C++11 a if statement could be

```
if(condition)
if(type name = initializer)
```

and `name` would be evaluated as a `bool` to determine the condition.  In C++11/14 the rules expended to allow

```
if(condition)
if(type name = initializer)
if(type name{initializer})
```

Where, again, `name` is evaluted as a `bool` after it is initialized to determine the condition.

Starting in C++17 though you will be able to declare a variable in a if statement as a compound statement like a for loop which allows you to initialize the variable with parentheses.

```
if (std::ifstream input("input_file.txt"); input.is_open())
{
    // do stuff with input
}
else
{
    // do other stuff with input
}
```

It should be noted though that this is just syntactic sugar and the above code is actually translated to

```
{
    std::ifstream input("input_file.txt")
    if (input.is_open())
    {
        // do stuff with input
    }
    else
    {
        // do other stuff with input
    }
}
```

Comment: You *can* declare a variable in a *condition* all the way back to C++03. It's just that the form of initialization is limited.

Comment: @FredLarson Answr updated.  I did have it wrong.  Back in C++98/03 you could declare a variable.

Comment: @NathanOliver Does it not also limit the scope of `input`? Or is it just sugar?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Update noted, answer upvoted, comment removed.

Comment: @user3358771 All versions limit the scope.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah, yes.. Didn't notice the extra curlies in your last code earlier.. Your last two versions have the extra `is_open()`, is that necessary or? Mark B's answer seems to suggest that `(input_file.txt)` would not be legal even in C++17.. I guess what I'm asking is, is your last two versions using `is_open()` for the conditional because the `fstream input("...")` can't directly be used as the conditional?

Comment: @user3358771 The `is_open()` part is not really needed, I just put it there to show you can make it more complicated.  Everywhere I have tried it with parentheses has worked and I am looking for the standardiess to confirm.

Comment: @user3358771 Okay, `if (std::ifstream input("input_file.txt"))` is illegal period.  `if (std::ifstream input("input_file.txt"); some_condition)` is legal C++17.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if ifstreams can be chained within the conditional while using the curlies? At least this fails: `if (std::ifstream ifs1{ "1.txt" } && std::ifstream ifs2{ "2.txt" })`. Putting them in separate if's of course works..

Comment: @user3358771 From what I see in the standard it look like you can only declare a single variable.

Comment: I think you will find the test is `!fail()`. Use a stream in a bool context causes `operator bool` to be called which in turn calls `!fail()`. Slightly different to `is_open()`

Answer (score 8):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if that code is not legal (This site is pretty reputable but I can hunt for the standard reference if desired). You *can* declare variables in an if condition but they must be initialized by `=` or `{}`. So assuming you have at least C++11 you can do:

```
if (std::ifstream input{"input_file.txt"})
    ;
```

Comment: OP's code is still not legal in C++17. The new *init-statement* feature doesn't change the required form of the *condition*.